# Downloaded Xcode 6.3 from store but 6.2 is still launching

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded Xcode 6.3 from the Mac Store but when I launch Xcode, it still opens 6.2. I've tried restarting the Mac. Also when I go to the Mac store and search for Xcode it prompts me to Open Xcode 6.3, but this opens 6.2 (it also indicates that its been successfully downloaded).

Im running OS X 10.10.2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Im now running OS X 10.10.3

**Update2**
When I launch Xcode, on the launch screen, it has Version 6.2, but I downloaded and installed 6.3.

[image]

Comment: Change default XCode to version 6.3 !!

Comment: @RoNiT Where do I change this?

Comment: Rightclick your .xcodeproj file > Get Info > Open with > Xcode 6.3

Comment: @DevC Are you seeing two different Xcode apps in your Applications folder?

Comment: @RoNiT please see the above screenshot. Its not that the project is opening with 6.2, its that Xcode itself is 6.2 though I installed 6.3

Comment: @TimMcClure Nope I am not, whats strange is that is says it was last modified today at the time when I downloaded it from the store but when I right click on the application and check its info it still says Version 6.2

Comment: @DevC have you tried deleting the Xcode app and then installing it via Mac App Store? Or maybe download directly from Apple's developer download page (although I cannot remember if they offer it as a standalone download)

Comment: @TimMcClure I havent tried deleting it but Ill try that now. Was hoping I would not need to download and install again.

Comment: @TimMcClure still launching the old xcode from Applications

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I haven't tried updating from Apple's developers page

Comment: @AshishMusale I got it working. Download the latest OS if there is an update, delete XCode from Applications, 'Get' Xcode from the Mac Store, and if it installs 6.2 again (like it did for me) go back to the Mac Store and 'update' should be there. Click Update. Hope it works

Comment: same problem. This should not be happening with apple technology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working. Download the latest OS if there is an update, delete Xcode from Applications, 'Get' Xcode from the Mac App Store, and if it installs 6.2 again (like it did for me) go back to the Mac App Store and 'update should be there.

Comment: This worked for me, but I only needed the first 2 steps of deleting Xcode and then getting it again from App Store.

Comment: @prototypical that's great!